# How to find out if there is a request pending on SignalR client?

Tags: javascript, signalr

I'm trying to figure out whether there are any pending requests on the SignalR client so that I can show a "Loading" indicator until all of the requests are processed. Here is what I am doing currently:

```
// some variable to hold whether there are pending requests
var isProcessing = false;


function ProcessSomeData(data)
{
    isProcessing = true;

    hub.server.setUserData(data).done(function () {
        isProcessing = false;
    });
}
```

Then I look at `isProcessing` to see if all the requests are processed. This is inaccurate (sometimes `isProcessing` gets set to false when there are still requests in progress), so I was wondering if there is a way to determine whether the SignalR client is "busy" processing requests or just idle. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any other solution in SignalR library but I did some workaround for this behaviour before. I send a loading message before send a real data from hub. Code is like this:

```
public void Send(string message)
{
     var username = Context.User.Identity.Name;
     context.Clients.User(username).loadingMessages();
     //-- Do you process here
     context.Clients.User(username).yourMessage(message);
}
```

And at javascript you should create loadingMessages implementation:

```
// some variable to hold whether there are pending requests
var isProcessing = false;

$.connection.hub.client.loadingMessages = function(){
   isProcessing = true;
   //-- Some Dom manupulation may be
}

function ProcessSomeData(data)
{


    hub.server.setUserData(data).done(function () {
       isProcessing = false;
    });
}
```

This is not a best solution but may be give you some approach.Thanks.